# Create form for complex type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a form for the model below:

```
public class SPObject
{      
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

A simple and basic example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the inbuilt 'Add Controller' function in VS2013? It should create all the CRUD views for you.

Comment: Does the form have to contain validation?  What does a `Card` object consist of?